# can we pass someother trigger context variable in before insert operation instead of passing null?

Tags: apex, before-trigger

my implementation:

```java
trigger accTrigger on Account (before update, after insert, before insert, after delete, after update) 
{
    switch on Trigger.OperationType {
       when BEFORE_INSERT
       {
           accHandler.updatesalesRep(Trigger.new, null);
       }
       when BEFORE_UPDATE
       {
           accHandler.updatesalesRep(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);           
       }
    }
}
```

Handler Class:

```java
public class accHandler {
    public static void updatesalesRep(List<Account> accList, Map<Id, Account> mapOldAcc) 
    {
        Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Account> newAcc = new List<Account>();
        
        for (Account acc : accList) {
            if (mapOldAcc != null) {
                if (mapOldAcc.get(acc.Id).OwnerId != acc.OwnerId) {
                    ownerIds.add(acc.OwnerId);
                }
            } else {
                ownerIds.add(acc.OwnerId);
            }
        }
        
        if (!ownerIds.isEmpty()) {
            Map<Id, User> mapUser = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id IN :ownerIds]);
            
            for (Account ac : accList) {
                ac.Sales_Rep__c = mapUser.get(ac.OwnerId).Name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger.old and Trigger.oldMap are null, already, so you can safely do:

```
switch on Trigger.OperationType {
    when BEFORE_INSERT, BEFORE_UPDATE {
        accHandler.updatesalesRep(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);           
    }
}
```

Note that with the new [Safe Navigation Operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SafeNavigationOperator.htm), you can simplify your handler, too:

```
for (Account acc : accList) {
    if (mapOldAcc?.get(acc.Id).OwnerId != acc.OwnerId) {
        ownerIds.add(acc.OwnerId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering sfdxfox. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could pass in `trigger.newMap` for the before insert case, but it would be null so you would be typing more (and making things less clear) to get the same result.

You could also pass in an empty map (which would allow you to remove one of the if/else in your handler).

But honestly, this doesn't seem like something you should be using a trigger for. Getting the current owner's name could be accomplished by making `Sales_Rep__c` a formula field.

Comment: Thanks for answering Derek F. It really helped me.